# How does receiver side know data on a single channel was empty if there are multiple senders send data on that channel?

Tags: go, channel

I have a simple example and don't know how to fix it to make it works as I expected.

It should print `Result: 30` but the screen showed: **fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!**

I think the problem at here is the statement `for val := range data`. It still wait to receive data when the data channel was empty. But I don't how to solve it, please help me out.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func senderSide(data chan int) {
    num := 5
    for i := 1; i <= num; i++ {
        data <- i
    }
    // close(data) //panic: send on closed channel if uncomment it
}

func receiverSide(data chan int, resp chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for val := range data {
        sum += val
    }
    resp <- sum
}

func main() {
    data := make(chan int)
    resp := make(chan int)
    go senderSide(data)
    go senderSide(data)
    go receiverSide(data, resp)
    result := <-resp
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", result) //result = 30
}
```

Comment: That's how channels work. When receiving on a channel, it waits until there is something to receieve. Likewise when sending on a channel, it waits until something is available to receive it. This is covered in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Comment: Note that executing `receiverSide` in a goroutine is silly here, since main doesn't do anything until `receiverSide` is done.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question, but the deadlock is simple to explain. You never close the `data` chan, so the loop in `recevierSide` never closes, because it's constantly waiting for more data.

This in turn means it never sends the response, so the program deadlocks.

Comment: I mean that If I have only a goroutine `go senderSide(data)` and adding `close(data)` at the end senderSide function, the program will print `Result: 15` right? And I want the program should print `Result: 30` when I call one more `go senderSide(data)` and so on. How can I achieve it?

Comment: But multiple goroutines are using that channel. Close will cause **panic: send on closed channel** when other goroutine send data on it.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait until both goroutines finish to close the channel.

Comment: Sorry, but I  really don't know when both goroutines finish to close. Adding `close(data)` at the end `senderSide` function didn't work.

Comment: @TungLuu, use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for both senders to finish, then close the channel.

Comment: @Peter thank you so much, your solution is great. It works :D